# (vanilla javascript calculator) How do I get the nodeValue from this nodeList?

Tags: javascript, html

What I'm trying to do is grab the node that was clicked and add it to the innerHTML of the screen I have set up. However, it seems as though my for loop is completing before I can get that value. In my case, keys[3] doesn't exist, so it is returning an error, but I would like to have the loop stop on the 'clicked' element and grab that value.

[JS Bin snippit](http://jsbin.com/foramagoja/edit?html,css,js,console,output)

Comment: Please post the relevant code here.

Comment: Never use `.innerHTML +=`

Comment: to add to what @Oriol said, use `insertAdjacentHTML('beforeend', yourhtmlgoeshere)` as a faster equivalent - see [insertAdjacentHTML](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/insertAdjacentHTML) documentation for other values in place of `beforeend`

Answer (score 1):

What you need to do is use `textContent` instead of `nodeValue` to get 1, 2, or 3. Next, use `this` instead of `keys[i]`.

```js
var screen = document.getElementById("screen");
var keys = document.querySelectorAll('.keys');

for (var i = 0; i < keys.length; i++) {
  keys[i].addEventListener('click', function() {
    screen.innerHTML += this.textContent;
  });
}
```

```css
#calculator {
  width: 500px;
  height: 600px;
  border: 1px solid black;
}
#screen {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100px;
  border: 1px solid black;
}
.keys {
  width: 24%;
  display: inline-block;
  border: 1px solid black;
  height: 50px;
  cursor: pointer;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width">
  <title>JS Bin</title>
</head>

<body>
  <div id="calculator">
    <div id="screen">

    </div>
    <div class="keys">1</div>
    <div class="keys">2</div>
    <div class="keys">3</div>

  </div>
</body>

</html>
```

Now this should be working properly as it gets the text content, and instead of `keys[i]`, it uses `this` as `i` doesn't exist outside the loop. `this` references the current element. You could always define the anonymous function outside, and use a for-each loop.

Comment: Thank you so much!

Comment: You should really define the function _outside_ of the loop (and generally avoid defining functions within loops)[http://eslint.org/docs/rules/no-loop-func], there is no reason to create a bunch of function contexts when one would suffice.

Comment: @RobM. You're right, and you could substitute the for loop with a forEach.

Comment: @AndrewL. I thought the forEach method was for arrays only. Or could I access it with Array.prototype.slice.call(keys) in this case since keys has a length?

Comment: @DevoidDesign [Here](https://jsfiddle.net/cnnr2zz1/) you go. This version uses a for-each and an outside function for better efficiency

Answer (score 0):

I would use let not var. This works:

```
for (let i = 0; i < keys.length; i++) {
   keys[i].addEventListener('click', function() {
   screen.innerHTML += keys[i].firstChild.nodeValue;
 });
```

Ok: Edit:

```
var screen = document.getElementById("screen");
var keys = document.querySelectorAll('.keys');
var val = 0;
screen.innerHTML = 0;

for (let i = 0; i < keys.length; i++) {
  keys[i].addEventListener('click', function() {

  val += parseInt(keys[i].firstChild.nodeValue);
  screen.innerHTML = val;
  });
}
```

And to clarify: I would (allways) use let i = 0 in a loop because it also works with async operations in a loop because it is a block scope.

Not applying to this particular case but try this:

```
var x = [1,2,3,4];

for(var i = 0; i<x.length; i++){

  window.setTimeout(function(){

    console.log(i);
  },Math.random())

}

//console.log returns: 4 4 4 4

for(let i = 0; i<x.length; i++){

  window.setTimeout(function(){

   console.log(i);
 },Math.random())

}

 //console.log returns 0 1 2 3
```

See the difference?

Comment: Why would you prefer to use `<let>`randomly, why does it work? Please provide some information and context when answering a question.

Comment: @user3791775 The OP had no `parseInt` but nice use of `let`

Comment: @Andrew The title of the OP starts with (Vanilla javascript CALCULATOR) so I presumed it was about calculating numbers

Comment: @user3791775 Yeah, but notice there aren't any operations being implemented yet. I'm guessing it's for inputting numbers for calculation :)

Comment: @AndrewL. Ok, peace out.

Answer (score 0):

The `i` variable exists only in the loop, it does not exist in the `click` event.

Try changing this:

```
screen.innerHTML += keys[i].firstChild.nodeValue;
```

To this:

```
screen.innerHTML += this.outerHTML;
```

Answer (score 0):

```
for (var i = 0; i < keys.length; i++) {
       keys[i].addEventListener('click', function(e) {
           console.log(e, e.target)
       screen.innerHTML += e.target.innerHTML;
     });
```

i would use e.target to get anything out of div.
this feels more clean.
That is if you goal is to get any text that is in a container.
Although this would not be the most effective way to make a calculator.

http://jsbin.com/rifekejivi/1/edit?html,css,js,console,output

Answer (score 0):

just add a click event to the body, and check if the targets class name equals key, then add the textContent of the target to screen

```
"use strict"

var screen = document.getElementById("screen");
var keys = document.querySelectorAll('.keys');

// for (var i = 0; i < keys.length; i++) {
// keys[i].addEventListener('click', function() {
//  screen.innerHTML += this.textContent;
// });
// }

document.body.addEventListener('click', function(e) {
  let target = e.target;
  switch(target.className) {
    case "keys":
       screen.innerHTML += target.textContent;
      break;
    default:
  }
})
```